# vscode extensions: debug auto tests: debugger suddenly stops on "step over"

Tags: debugging, testing, visual-studio-code, automated-tests, vscode-extensions

I wrote test code for an extension I'm writing in and for vscode. When I debug my tests step-by-step the debugger sometimes suddenly stops.

I cannot pin it down to specific commands being run, so I'm really tapping in the dar.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this on accident: It *looks like* the debugger is being stopped, because of `mocha`'s timeout constraint (mocha is the test framework vscode uses by default for its extension).

For me it helped increasing that timeout:

In **index.ts** a `Mocha` object is being created. You can change time timeout like this:

```
const mocha = new Mocha({
    ui: 'tdd',
    color: true
});
mocha.timeout (5000000); // increased timeout
```